# Avoid using set! into functional programming style algorithm

Tags: list, random, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm not sure if I can ask this question here. If this is not the right place, please tell me and I will delete it.

I'm learning Racket and someone has told me something about avoiding using `set!` in functional programming style. But I'm confused, I don't understand the meaning of "functional programming style". Just to learn, I want to ask this question.

I have the following code:

```
 (define lst1 '())

 (do ([i n (- i 1)])
   ((zero? i))
   ; Get an item.
   (set! item (random-chooser original-list))
   ; Insert it into an auxiliary list, lst1
   (set! lst1 (cons item lst1))
   ; Remove the item from the original list
   (set! original-list (remove item original-list)))

 (append (list lst1) (list original-list))))))
```

This code is working perfectly. I have to choose `n` items from `original-list` list randomly, without repetition. And then create a list with two sub-lists with the `n` items chosen in `lst1` and as the second sub-list, the remaining items on `original-list`.

Is there a better way to do this without using `set!`?

Comment: your edit actually invalidates two out of the three answers. as I understand the rules, we're not supposed to do this on SO. I feel obliged to rollback your edit. :) you can always ask a new question, with the changed requirements. :)

Comment: @WillNess If I ask another question, similar to this one, I will get a lot of down votes because people will have that it is a duplicate.

Comment: but it is not a duplicate. here you asked for *k* randomly picked values, there you would specify that a user-supplied function must be used. also include link to this question, as a background.

Comment: This question is closed (because I have an answer), but I'm asking how to avoid using `set!`. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to remove the use of `set!` and explicit loops, you need to use recursion, with the "updated" values being passed in as parameters.

Scheme has some nice syntactic sugar around [`letrec`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._letrec%29%29) (recursive `let`, used for bindings that can reference themselves), which allows you to create and call a function in one go: [named `let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._let%29%29). This is often used for looping, so the function is often called `loop`, but it can be called anything else. The important thing is to call it with modified parameters when looping, and not to call it when the loop is over.

```
(define (take-random n lst)
  ; Syntactic sugar that creates a 3-parameter function called `loop` and calls it
  ; with the values `n`, `'()` and `lst`
  (let loop ((n n)
             (picked '())
             (lst lst))
    ; If the loop counter reaches zero or if there are no more items to take
    (if (or (zero? n) (null? lst))
        ; Then combine the picked items and the remaining unpicked items
        (list picked lst)
        ; Otherwise, pick a random item from the list
        (let ((item (random-chooser lst)))
          ; And loop again, decreasing the loop counter to be nearer zero,
          ; adding the picked item to the list of picked items, and removing
          ; it from the list of remaining items to pick from
          (loop (- n 1)
                (cons item picked)
                (remove item lst))))))

;; Examples
(take-random 3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
; => ((4 1 6) (2 3 5))
(take-random 3 '(1 2))
; => ((2 1) ())
```

[Óscar López's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53612375/1406083) is a good presentation of the more functional way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have asked another question about when to use `define` and when to use `let`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637079/when-to-use-define-and-when-to-use-let-in-racket. And I see in your answer you only use `define` to define a function, and in function's body, you use `let`.

Answer (score 2):

In functional programming we write code by composing existing procedures whenever possible. All of the operations you're doing can be expressed by using [list procedures](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html):

```
(define n 5)
(define lst '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))

(let ((shuffled (take (shuffle lst) n)))
  (list shuffled (remove* shuffled lst)))

=> '((5 8 9 6 2) (0 1 3 4 7))
```

In the end you'll have two lists, the first contains `n` elements randomly chosen from the original list, and the second contains the remaining elements.

In functional programming we try really hard to avoid explicit loops (we use recursion in its place) and `set!`. We use existing procedures, composition, and create new data (say, lists) instead of modifying existing data.

I can tell that you come from a procedural background, it's kinda hard to let go of loops and assignments, but that's the beauty of functional programming: it makes you think differently about how you solve problems. Mutating data is the source of many difficulties, especially when doing concurrent programming, that's why FP avoids it at all costs.

Note that mutating data is avoided as much as possible, but Scheme, being an *impure* functional programming language allows it. For instance, the `shuffle` procedure must change state at some point, when picking random values. But it's all encapsulated away, and in normal, day-to-day programming you can do most of your work without ever using `set!`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it clarifies me a lot! But I don't know how to use your example to make mime more functional style because `random-chooser` it's my own function and it doesn't fit with `(take (shuffle lst) n)`.

Comment: One of the first things to remember when doing functional programming, is to reuse existing procedures, `random-chooser` is probably not necessary. Having said that, I would need to understand what it's doing.

Comment: `random-chooser` is **REALLY** necessary. Without explain what it does internally, it returns an item from the list I have passed as a parameter.

Comment: I understand, you have an external dependency on `random-chooser`. It's a shame, having to delete one element at a time forces us to do a loop. Billy's solution is a good one, and as you can see, it uses recursion for looping and avoids `set!`. I prefer my own version :) but if you _have to_ use that other procedure, there's little I can do to improve it. I would argue that the need to use `random-chooser` is making the solution less functional in style.

Comment: I'm studying a master's degree and I need to use that function. My solution is working perfectly, I only want to know how the code would be in functional programming style. Thanks a lot for your time and support.

Comment: I think I can use loops and `set!`. I do not think I'm going to fail the subject if I use them.

Comment: @VansFannel of course not :) . One of the nice things of Scheme is that it can be adapted to many programming styles - procedural, functional, object-oriented, logic. At its core it's a functional language, and I'm an advocate of using it like that, it's the idiomatic way. Surely you can keep using it in a procedural way, but you'd be missing out on its elegance and expressiveness. Just compare the number of lines of code that takes to solve the same problem in different styles ;)

Comment: using ``remove*`` is incorrect in case there were duplicates in the input. simple `drop n` is sufficient, or better if `take+drop` are fused into one function returning the two parts of the list at once (like Haskell's `splitAt`). then, using "`shuffle`" performs *extraneous* effort (in a *strict* language), randomly picking *all* of the elements in the input instead of just *n*. it is also incorrect in case of duplicates, as Q is about picking *n* elements "without repetition" but "`shuffle`" is clearly purely positional.  /sorry/ :)

Comment: @WillNess you’re right about remove* , it’ll remove more than expected if there are dups. I don’t agree with the shuffling part, it really depends on what’s the logic in random-chooser, the way I interpret it OP just wants to make sure of not picking the same exact element twice, I don’t think he cares about repeated values, and if he cares then I don’t think that dups are allowed in the first place. Further clarification is needed.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez ah, this actually makes much more sense. perhaps it was indeed what they meant, not to pick same *position* more than once. I was being much too literal. :/ then using shuffle is correct and even seems ingenious; but still it makes too many calls to ``(random)`` (internally, presumably). :)

Comment: @WillNess, @ÓscarLópez. Maybe I should have chosen a more generic function name, like `function1`, instead of `random-chooser`.

Comment: I have found this definition in Wikipedia: "Functional programming (FP) is a programming paradigm — a style of building the structure and elements of computer programs — that treats computation as the evaluation of mathematical functions and avoids changing-state and mutable data.", and I love it!! But, what changing-state means?

Comment: I've been chatting at freenode and now I think I have understood what is FP: use functions, without changing anything and using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

`shuffle` is really a good solution and very functional. Functional style forbids mutation/change of existing/defined variable values (thus no `set!`). Rather one creates/copies an existing object and mutates it or creates it in mutated form. `shuffle` creates/copies the original list in mutated order.

You can use `take` and `drop` to get or leave the first `n` position of any list. Or use the `split-at` function.

However, since this returns the result as values but the task was to return a list, you use `let-values` to bind the two return results and bind them into a single list.

```
(define (choose-n-and-rest lst n)
  (let-values ([(chosen rest) (split-at (shuffle lst) n)])
    (list chosen rest)))
```

or:

```
(define (choose-n-and-rest lst n)
  (let ((new-lst (shuffle lst)) ; so that `take` & `drop` use the same shuffled list
    (list (take new-list n) (drop new-list n))))
```

But as you can read [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._drop%29%29https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._drop%29%29), `split-at` might be slightly more efficient than the combination of `take` and `drop`.

Try it out with:

```
(choose-n-and-rest '(a b c d e 1 2 3 4 5) 3) 
;; e.g. '((a 4 2) (1 b 3 5 c e d))
```

By the way, `set!` or better: mutating functions is/are not completely forbidden in lisp-style functional programming.
The reason is performance.
Copying every lengthy list is costly.
An example is common-lisp's `nreverse` which changes order of original list (reverses the order). The non-mutating `reverse` creates a new list with elements in reverse order. But for that it has to copy.
If you mutate local variables (defined by `let`), it can lead to gain of performance - but very cautiously, of course, since mutation is a dangerous thing.