# When to use define and when to use let in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm learning racket and I have a question about when to use `define` and when to use `let`.

I have this function:

```
(define my-function
  (lambda (param1 param2 list1)
    (/
     (count
      (lambda (x)

        (define a (param1 (remove x list1)))

        (define b (drop-right x 1))

        (define c (param2 a x-sin-clase))

        (eq? (last x) (last c)))
      (cdr list1))
     (length (cdr list1)))))
```

Without knowing what the above function does. Is it correct to use `define` inside the function body?

I have read somewhere that `define` is used to declare global variables and `let` is used to declare local variables. I've look in racket's documentation but it doesn't talk about any difference.

Comment: One difference: Internal `define`s are in a mutually recursive scope (including mut-rec functions), `let` bindings are not, but there are also other style reasons

Comment: @AlexKnauth Sorry, but I haven't understood anything about your comment. Thanks.

Comment: In `(let ([x expr-1] [y expr-2]) body)`, expr-1 and expr-2 cannot refer to `x` or `y`. . . . . . . However, in `(block (define x expr-1) (define y expr-2) body)`, both expr-1 and expr-2 can have references to `x` and `y`.

Comment: Technically `define`s are only "allowed" on the top level. When used in local definition context, them are just syntax sugar and will be expanded into appropriate `let` form.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One difference: Internal defines are in a mutually recursive scope, but let bindings are not.

This means than in a `let`:

```
(let ([x expr-1] [y expr-2])
  body)
```

The `expr-1` and `expr-2` cannot refer to `x` or `y`. More concretely,

```
(let ([x (stream-cons 1 y)] [y (stream-cons 2 x)])
  x)
;error=> y: unbound identifier in: y
```

And if `x` or `y` is defined outside of the `let`, expr-1 and expr-2 will refer to the *outer* definitions, and not the ones introduced by the let. Concretely:

```
(define x 'outer)
(let ([x 'inner] [y x]) ; <- this x refers to outer,
  y)                    ;    so y is 'outer
;=> 'outer
```

However, internal defines have a mutually recursive scope, which means that in

```
(block
  (define x expr-1)
  (define y expr-2)
  body)
```

The `expr-1` and `expr-2` *can* refer to `x` or `y`. Concretely,

```
(require racket/block)

(block
  (define x (stream-cons 1 y))
  (define y (stream-cons 2 x))
  (stream->list (stream-take x 5)))
;=> (list 1 2 1 2 1)
```

#### The Scope of a `define`

```
....A....
(define (f)
  (define t1 ..B..)
  (define x ..C..)
  (define t2 ..D..)
  ....E....)
....F....
```

The `x` is visible everywhere in the body of `f`, but not outside that. That means it's visible in `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`, but not in A or F.

#### The Scope of a `let`

```
....A....
(define (f)
  (let ([t1 ..B..]
        [x ..C..]
        [t2 ..D..])
    ....E....))
....F....
```

Here the `x` is visible everywhere in the body of the `let`, but not outside that. That means it's visible in `E`, but not in A, B, C, D, or F.

#### The Scope of a `let*`

```
....A....
(define (f)
  (let* ([t1 ..B..]
         [x ..C..]
         [t2 ..D..])
    ....E....))
....F....
```

Here the `x` is visible everywhere in the body of the `let*` and in `let*` bindings that come *after* it, but not outside that. That means it's visible in `D` and `E`, but not in A, B, C, or F.

#### The Scope of a `letrec`

```
....A....
(define (f)
  (letrec ([t1 ..B..]
           [x ..C..]
           [t2 ..D..])
    ....E....))
....F....
```

The `x` is visible everywhere in the body of the `letrec` and in the bindings of the `letrec`, but not outside that. That means it's visible in `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`, but not in A or F.

The scope of variables in `letrec` and the scope of local `define` variables are very similar because both `letrec` and `define` work with mutually recursive scopes.

Comment: So, is it better to use let inside a body function? Thanks.

Comment: I find `let` most useful when I need to "change" the function input to be a better "more consistent" form of itself. For example if a function takes either a `Symbol` or a `[Listof Symbol]`, but I want to write the body of the function as if it were consistently a `[Listof Symbol]`, I could use a `let` to shadow the argument and make it a list. `(define (f x) (let ([x (if (list? x) x (list x))]) ....body....))`

Comment: I'm a bit overwhelmed by all these various scoping's. Are there any statistics on the % amount of their use? So far been using mainly define's and a bit of lets and it seemed enough. Do we need so many options?

Comment: I don't know any specific statistics, but in the code I've read or worked on, internal define is much more common than let. I normally only use let in special circumstances like when either define isn't allowed or I'm intentionally shadowing with a "normalized" version, for everything else I use define

Comment: shadowing with a "normalized" version?

Comment: The comment above with changing `x` to a better "more consistent" form of itself, making it always a list, instead of sometimes a list and sometimes a symbol, is one example of a way to "normalize" `x`.

Answer (score -2):

I've finally understood what I have read that `define`'s variable are "global variables".

In the book The Scheme Programming Language Fourth Edition, R. Kent Dybvig, section [2.6. Top Level Definitions](https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/start.html#./start:h6) says:

> The variables bound by let and lambda expressions are not visible
>   outside the bodies of these expressions.

Comment: `define`'s variables are _not_ global if the definition is within a local scope. The `x` in `(define (f) (define x 5) ....body....)` is only visible inside the body of `f`, not outside.

Comment: @AlexKnauth Maybe I haven't understood my professor. He said: "Define should be used only to define global variables. To define local variables from a function, let or let * must be used. If not, global variables may interfere with the local functioning of a function."

Comment: Which language _exactly_ is your professor talking about? That sounds like a weird language feature and I want to try it out.

Comment: He's talking about Scheme.

Comment: Which variant of Scheme? R5RS, R6RS, Chez Scheme, Guile, Chicken, etc. which one?

Comment: We are developing our exercises with racket. We use DrRacket.

Comment: I just tried using an internal define that way in Racket, and the `x` wasn't visible outside, it wasn't "global." So what did your professor mean by that?

Comment: I don't know. I will ask him. Maybe tomorrow I will get an answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AlexKnauth He said that is about Closure, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)